# How can I make my implementation of IObservable<T> multithreaded?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, system.reactive

I wrote an implementation based on the examples at [ Rx DEVHOL202] and http : //rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc48

Here is my code.  http://csharp.pastebin.com/pm2NAPx6

1. It works, but the calls to OnNext are not NonBlocking, which is what i would like to implement to simulate a network read and asynchronously handing off each chunk of bytes as it is read to a handler [ which is not shown here in full but might cache results and do further processing ].

   What is a good way of doing that?
2. Once the Exception gets thrown, all the subsequent OnNext()s are not processed!!
   If I dont explicitly exit the loop and indicate completion.
   Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend *against* trying to implement your own `IObservable`. The implicit rules go beyond thread safety and into method call ordering.

Usually you would return `IObservable` instances from methods, but if you need a class that implements it directly, you should wrap a `Subject`:

```
public class SomeObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
{
        private Subject<T> subject = new Subject<T>();

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            return subject.Subscribe(observer);
        }
}
```

1. You need to be careful about how you support this from your observer (as you may have shared data), but you can make your handling of the calls asynchronous in one of two ways:

- Call `ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)` (or `ThreadPool` if you are pre-4.0) before you call `Subscribe`. This causes messages to be routed through a scheduler (in this case, a task)
- Pass the `IScheduler` to the `Observer` constructor
- Start an asynchronous task/thread from your subscriber

2. This is the expected functionality. The contract between `IObservable` and `IObserver` is `(OnNext)* (OnCompleted | OnError)?`, which is to say "zero or more calls to OnNext, optionally followed by EITHER OnCompleted or OnError". After `OnCompleted|OnError`, it is invalid to call `OnNext`.

All the operators in Rx (`Where`, `Select`, etc) enforce this rule, even if the source doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but why can't you just execute whatever logic you have on a different `Thread`, or if it's small enough push it on a `ThreadPool`?

Here is an example:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=>
{
    _paidSubj.OnNext(this); // Raise PAID event 
});
```

I'm confused about the data type on `Subject`, I have never seen that class in C#... is it something that you created? Is `OnNext` an event that gets raised or is it just a method? If `OnNext` is an event, then you can use `BeginInvoke` to invoke it asynchronously:

```
_paidSubj.OnNext.BeginInvoke(this, null, null);
```

**Update:**

An important thing that will happen if you implement this kind of asynchronous behavior: if you notify an `IObserver` by passing the `Order`, you might actually have some inconsistencies when you try to read the data in the observer (namely the order buffer) while the Order continues to modify the buffer in its `Read` thread. So there are at least two ways to solve this:

1. Restrict access to the memory which will get modified by using locks.
2. Only notify the observer with the relevant information that you want it to see:
   a. By passing the information as a value (not as a reference).
   b. By creating an immutable structure that transmits the information.

P.S.
Where did you get `Subject` from? Is `Subject` supposed to be an `OrderObserver`?

Comment: Subject is an Rx thing, it represents something that is both `IObservable` and `IObserver`, and is often used as an "adapter"